# Gorilla/Mux & Websocket Race Condition. Is this safe?

Tags: go, websocket, race-condition, gorilla

I'm working on a websocket and recently started doing some tests for race conditions using `race`.
`go run -race serve.go`

Getting this result:

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x0000019ab4a8 by goroutine 95:
  go-api/client.ServeWs()

Previous write at 0x0000019ab4a8 by goroutine 117:
  go-api/client.ServeWs()
```

I'm using `gorilla/mux` and am upgrading one of the requests to websockets. I wasn't sure if it was being caused by something else, but even this pretty simple setup is still showing a race condition.  My *guess* was because `websocket` was being written to by both routines at the same time, but as long as both requests get upgraded, does it matter? Or is it possible a connection is being dropped due to the race condition?

```
    //serve.go
    mux.HandleFunc("/data", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        client.ServeWs(w, r)
    })
```

```
//client.go
func ServeWs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
        CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
            return true
        },
    }

    _, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't write a variable from multiple goroutines without synchronization. Handlers are called from multiple goroutines, so you can't just write `upgrader`. Either use proper synchronization (if you do intend to use the same variable), or have each goroutine have their own variable: use a local `upgrader` var and not a package level one.

Comment: Because the upgrader is not dependent on the request,  you can create the upgrader at package-level: `var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{ ... fields as in ServeWs ... }`   and remove the assignment to `upgrader` from `ServeWs`.

Comment: @Zombo Don't know how I didn't realize this...overthinking I guess. If you can post the comment as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the upgrader is not dependent on the request, you can create the upgrader at package-level

```
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{ ... fields as in ServeWs ... }
```

and remove the assignment to the upgrader from ServeWs.

```
func ServeWs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
```